# How to prevent REST API misuse by adding random token or string and validating later on in Laravel 5

Tags: php, android, laravel-5

I have laravel based Website. I have to port website into android app. For that I have to create REST API for User management(User Registration, Password forgotten and Login).
For registration I could send json in the form  of

> {   "email" :"john.doe@gmail.com",   "password" : "secretPassword" }

But then API could be exploited with the help of bots. I am thinking of preventing it by sending some random token just Laravel does in forms(CSRF token). But I am not able to think how I will achieve that.
So how do I generate some token in laravel when users request to create new User and validate it upon getting that data-response?

Comment: So the question is how to (securely) authenticate your Android application against a REST API created using Laravel?

Comment: You forgot to ask the question. But how you wrote it I think this question is going to end up primarily opinion-based. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @N.B. - No mate, I am trying to create a secure REST API invulnerable to bots.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois-Thanks

Comment: If a bot isn't able to authenticate, then your question is how to perform authentication that's resilient against dictionary attacks.

Comment: @N.B. - I think I am not able to communicate properly. I want to create API for user REGISTRATION which bots can not exploit. For e.g. for Client 's website they send random token in registration form and once users has filled up form and hit send to server then that token is checked and if that token is verified then only user is created

Comment: This question is pretty clear, so I don't know why everyone has been having trouble understanding. Paraphrasing: "A registration/reset/login endpoint won't be guarded by any type of auth, so how do you prevent a bot from repeatedly trying to register/reset/login users?"